# MSM Control Panel

Tags: multi-site-manager, system

I have 2 sites setup using MSM, but I am having a slight issue with the second sites control panel theme.

My current setup is as follows:

```
site1  
  List item
  index.php
  admin.php
  system
  etc

site2
  index.php
  admin.php
  templates
```

I have edited the index.php and admin.php of site 2 to change the $system_path for site 2. When I go to www.site2.com/admin.php the admin panel is working, but there is no CSS, its just a white screen. I have tried editing the general configuration of site 2 but I'm struggling to get the control panel theme to work.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are that your Theme Folder URL is set to something relative (e.g., `/themes/`), which won't work unless you have the theme folder copied to both sites.

Try setting it to `http://site1.com/themes/`.

FWIW, I generally make my clients administer all sites in an MSM setup from one master control panel location (the parent domain, if you will) to prevent issues like these.

Comment: had a slight incorrect theme path! thanks